# How to copy a vector in a two dimensional vector

Tags: c++, vector

I'm trying to copy the content of an unidimensional vector in a two dimensional vector.

I've tried to use push_back()

```
vector<int> v;
vector<vector<int> > twov;

for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)
    twov.push_back(v[i])
```

But, of course, I receive a the following error:

```
error: reference to type 'const value_type' (aka 'const std::__1::vector<int, std::__1::allocator<int> >') could not bind to an lvalue of type 'value_type'
  (aka 'int')
```

Could you help me?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Avoid it, have an adapter wrapping that vector by reference and providing the (const and non-const) operators `T& operator () (std::size_t x, std::size_t y)`

Comment: I don't really know how to do it. I'm new on c++. Thanks.

Comment: @Elena  Please post the declarations of `twov` and `v`, instead of us trying to parse that error message.

Comment: We have no idea how to help you. How do you want to transform a unidimential vector into two-dimensional vector **logically**? Answer this question first, the coding will come later.

Comment: @SergeyA the twov vector has a 5x5 size and the v vector has a size of 25, so the idea is parse it. But I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing you have decide is how should the elements of `v` be distributed to `twov`.

Say `v` has `N` elements. Is `N` expected to be equal to `N1 x N2`, where `N1` is the number of rows and `N2` the number of columns?

If the answer is yes, you can create `twov` with `N1` 1-D `vectors` in it to start with.

```
size_t N = v.size();
size_t N1 = <Some value>;
size_t N2 = N/N1;
assert(N1*N2 == N);

// Create twov with the appropriate elements.
vector<vector<int> > twov(N1, vector<int>(N2));

// Now copy the elements from v to twov
for (size_t i = 0; i < N1; ++i )
{
   for (size_t j = 0; j < N2; ++j )
   {
      twov[i][j] = v[i*N2+j];
   }
}
```

If the structure of `twov` is not as clean as above, you'll have to come up with a different logic for copying the elements of `v` to `twov`.